# C# Excel interop, put a line break in the text of a cell in a Excel

Tags: c#, excel, com-interop

I am writing an Excel sheet using interop. In the sheet I need to put a set of sentences in to a cell. The text should be in a line break manner. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you assign a width to the cell, then set nowrap to false? Or do you need to line-break at specific place?

Comment: Hi I need to put multiple rows of data in a cell. And the rows should be row separated, meaning each row must start with a new row.

Comment: "each row must start with a new row"?? Row as in cell row/range, or newline within the same cell?

Comment: Sorry, each row should start with a new line within the same cell.

Comment: you have a track record of taking other people's answer and accept your own. It may defeat the purpose of reputation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It was done by either entering `"\r\n"` or `Environment.NewLine`. And also must remember to make `WrapText` property `true` in order to make the line breaks visible.

Comment: It's funny that the correct answer being downvoted. I'll give +1 for this.

Comment: while it creates anew line - it puts a small quadrant box at the end of each line - is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: Hi, sorry I did not get that.

Comment: @Rudy This answer is not correct. Excel will only use `\n` for the line break, the `\r` will remain as a visible character. In older Excel versions the `\r` will be drawn as a rectangle like user1514042 mentions, in newer versions it will be invisible but still present in the cell (you'd be able to move the text cursor beyond the visible end of line because [there is something else](http://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Zpr.png)).

Answer (score 7):

you can add style to cells programically as bellow

**worksheet.Cells.Style.WrapText = true;**

Answer (score 5):

New line within an Excel cell is the LF character, which is "\n" in C#. And do not forget to set the WrapText property of the cell to TRUE.

Answer (score 3):

New line within an Excel cell is the LF character, which is `"\n"` in C#.

Answer (score 2):

In **VB**, or **VBA**, I used to use `vbCrLf` (case sensitive) to separate sentences to separate lines in an Excel's Cell like the following:

```
Dim myString As String
myString = "First sentence" & vbCrLf & "Second sentence"
ActiveCell.ForumulaR1C1 = myString
```

In **C#**, I am rather confident that the C# equivalent of VB's `vbCrLf` is `"\r\n"`, hence:

```
myString = "First sentence\r\n" + "Second sentence"
```

Comment: vbCrLf works perfectly for VB.NET. I tried \r\n in VB.NET and it did not work. Great answer thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem but difference is I do not have access to the worksheet in code as I only pass it  to memorystream then create file as .csv type.

```
foreach (var s in propertyValues)
                streamWriter.WriteLine(s);

            streamWriter.Flush();
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

the I use it from here.

```
 subjExportData.FileStream = stream;
            subjExportData.FileName = string.Format("SubjectExport_{0}.csv", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmm"));
```

So the suggestion here to set text or cell wrap is not an option. Got it working using the above answer plus put a double quote before and after the text/string. The replace is to handle when the sentence has a double quote too inside it. So this solution handles, new line, comma and double quotes inside a sentence or paragraph.

```
if (value.ToString().Contains("\n"))
                                {
                                    value = value.ToString().Replace("\n", "\r\n");
                                    sb.Append('"'+ value.ToString().Replace(@"""", @"""""") + '"'+ ",");
                                }
```

Answer (score -2):

the answer of this issue is to add a "quot" in front and at the end of the string you want to display in your excel cell. In C# it would be something like (Convert.ToChar(34) + stringToExport + Convert.ToChar(34))

Comment: From a very quick test inserting a quoted multiline string (in which line breaks are not already `\r\n`) into excel, this does not work. Also this question has had an accepted answer for 2 years.

Comment: Well this worked fine for me.i didn't test it directly in excel. i was handling a copy event in  my app with a text containing a \r\n which i wanted to paste in an excel unique cell. the code above made it work.

Comment: From reading the OP's own answer you can see his issue was that the data did not contain `\r\n` already.

Comment: it's normal it doesn't work in excel directly. in excel you simply do alt+enter :)

Comment: well, my bad.. i thought he wanted to get rid of the "\r\n" when pasting his data to excel. Oops!! Well hope this feed helps someone in the future