# VBA Textbox invisible characters

Tags: excel, vba

When I put text from a spreadsheet into a form textbox the text has an extra character.

I placed the contents of the textbox in a cell alongside the original text from a spreadsheet cell. When I do a `LEN()` function on both the original text and the textbox text, the textbox text shows 25 and the original text is 24.

My question is why is the text different. I cannot figure out what this extra character is.
The text is 2 lines separated by a `CTL` and `LF`. I have also tried to use the `Trim()` function as well.

Has anyone figured this out? How can I compare the two texts so they are a match if the form text box adds some invisible character?

Below the first row is the `LEN()` function for A and B cells.
The second row is the values from the spreadsheet original cell and the second is the same value but put into a textbox on a form then output back to spreadsheet.

[image]

Comment: How do you "place the contents of the textbox"? Can you post the code that you're using to transfer the text around?

Answer (score 1):

Excel uses `vbLf` as the [line break character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8613850/11683) in cells. The `vbCr` character is not used for line breaking and [will](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613850/c-sharp-excel-interop-put-a-line-break-in-the-text-of-a-cell-in-a-excel#comment65333905_8652279) either display as a box (older Excels) or as a space (newer Excels).

If you want to put text in an Excel cell, replace `vbCrLf` with `vbLf` first.

Comment: In Excel 2013 at least, if you paste a `vbCrLf` into a cell from the clipboard, Excel will remove the `vbCr` as it comes off the clipboard. If you assign the cell value directly (i.e. `Range("A1").Value = "A" & vbCrLf & "B"`) it isn't removed.

Comment: Ok how do I do that type of replacement.

Comment: I am also getting these "_x000D_"

Answer (score 0):

To see most of the non-printable characters, change the font to Terminal and un-toggle `Wrap Text`

To find what character code it is, you can use the [`CODE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CODE-function-c32b692b-2ed0-4a04-bdd9-75640144b928) function:

```
= Code( Mid( A2, 6, 1 ) )
```

To remove non-printable ASCII characters, you can use the [`CLEAN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CLEAN-function-26f3d7c5-475f-4a9c-90e5-4b8ba987ba41) function:

```
= Clean( A2 )
```

To replace just the line feed characters with space:

```
= SUBSTITUTE( A2, CHAR( 10 ), " " )
```

[Remove spaces and nonprinting characters from text](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Remove-spaces-and-nonprinting-characters-from-text-023f3a08-3d56-49e4-bf0c-fe5303222c9d)

Comment: Clean does the trick on the sheet but how do I do that in code? Ok figured it out. :)    WorksheetFunction.Clean()

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved the problem.
I am using the worksheet function 
WorksheetFunction.Clean()
This works and I do not have to do anything else. 
Thanks for the input. :)